# Publish and/or subscribe to Platform Events between separate Orgs?

Tags: integration, webservices, platform-event

Does anyone have experience using Platform Events between separate orgs? I'm having trouble finding documentation or mention that something like this is possible. Basically I'd like to define a set of events that partnered companies can subscribe to so they can track our fulfillment process. Typically someone might set up web services or Connections as an integration solution, but I don't like how Connections couples our schema together. Web Services would require developer expertise than I'd like to compel them to pay for. A set of domain specific events is much more re-usable and less likely to change, than an object definition. In our use case of multiple integrated partners it would allow a given org to make changes without requiring a Connection change for every other org Connected to that object.

If it's not possible using more conventional Salesforce tooling, I know I could use a separate middleman pub/sub solution with Platform events, but I'd like to minimize moving parts.

Any info someone might have on the subject would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: salesforce2salesforce not an option for you?

Comment: Salesforce2salesforce connections couple the orgs together by schema which is what I'm trying to avoid. We have multiple partnered companies who would be using the same objects for a salesforce2salesforce connection and that limits our ability to change that published object as it may require changing the connection settings for every company subscribed to the same object. An event definition however would allow each integrated company to decide how they want to handle the event.

Comment: You can do [callouts from SFDC to publish an event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_publish_api.htm) to a remote SFDC (that you have authenticated to) but this requires knowledge of the event object on the target system

Comment: Maybe combine cropredy's idea with a local Platform Event trigger. The trigger could start an async process to make a callout to any interested system to publish the event there.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably the simplest solution. I was hoping there were a way to have a shared event-bus without using callouts, but it seems like this would work without too much heavy lifting. At least this way the "subscriber" Apex web service can be domain agnostic and reusable.

Comment: You could have an API where external orgs can register themselves as subscribers for an event. The platform event trigger would then check those to push the actual event notification out to.

Answer (score 8):

[Response](https://success.salesforce.com/0D53A00003S8Qud?fromEmail=1&s1oid=00D300000000iTz&s1nid=0DB30000000072L&s1uid=00530000003TSOB&s1ext=0&emkind=chatterCommentNotification&emtm=1520888481792) from [Jay Hurst (Salesforce PM)](https://success.salesforce.com/profile?u=00530000003TR2AAAW):

> Subscribing and publishing between orgs is not something that is natively supported today. We have discussed it, but it is not on the short term roadmap.
>
> You may want to look into the Salesforce Adapter for Salesforce Connect or Salesforce to Salesforce which are specifically suited to sharing records between orgs (which it sounds like what you want)

An [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000lfb9QAA) has been raised for this by [Raj](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/92620/raj) as probably the best way forward for getting native support for this.

Answer (score 2):

Subscribing to events from another org is not natively supported on the platform right now, here's an idea on the Idea Exchange to try and get this added:

[Publishing and subscribing events between two separate orgs natively](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000lfb9QAA)

Comment: Hey Raj, welcome to the site and thanks for the link! Added it to Daniel's answer to keep it up to date, but also reworded this so that it's not just a link-only answer.