# Publish Platform Event in SF org and subscribe to it in other org

Tags: rest-api, connected-apps, platform-event, workbench, cometd

The requirement is to publish a platform event in one salesforce org and subscribe to it in another salesforce org. In simple words, I need to publish a platform event from a salesforce app/org for an external app which is another salesforce app/org. I am not aware with APIs and stuff. I have already done Trailhead on **Platform Event Basics**. How do I connect or create channel between two different salesforce orgs so that platform event is flown between them.
Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Publish and/or subscribe to Platform Events between separate Orgs?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/208915/publish-and-or-subscribe-to-platform-events-between-separate-orgs)

Comment: use REST API to publish event from SFDC A; subscribe in SFDC B

Comment: Have a look at [Integration Patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_intro_overview.htm) for an overview of options